# Role of $d^2 = 0$ in chain complex

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, differential-forms

What is the motivation for requiring that the square of a differential be $0$ for a complex, aside from enabling us to speak of the homology of a complex?

Other homological notions like chain maps, homotopic maps, homotopy equivalences seem to be meaningful without any restriction on the differential (of course, no longer do homotopic maps induce isomorphisms on Homology, for Homology no longer is meaningful).

If we ignore any connections to Homology, is there some other moral reason to want that the differential square to $0$?

Comment: The word "moral" is totally inapplicable here, but something like "intuitive" or "heuristic"  would do.

Comment: Like you said, it enables us to speak of the homology of a complex.

Comment: @rschwieb "morally" and "moral" are actually often used to mean something similar to "intuitive" (but not exactly the same thing -althoug it's still a vague, unprecise notion), in some places at least. OP : Cartan famously said "if I could only understand the beautiful consequences following from the concise proposition $d^2=0$". An unsatisfactory answer would be : homology theory was built when many examples of this "$d^2=0$" phenomenon were found, like for instance the differential of the de Rham complex (unsatisfactory because it's probably not historically accurate)

Comment: Perhaps another point of view is that group extensions are interesting, and they are particular sequences $A\to B\to C$ with $g\circ f =0$. Chain complexes are then a generalization of that

Comment: From the other end, why a lot of commonly occurring complexes do have $d^2 = 0$: it often comes from the fact that an exact complex (for example a resolution) has $d^2 = 0$, and the fact that applying any functor preserves the condition that $d^2 = 0$ (while not that many functors preserve exactness).

Comment: @Max Interesting Cartan quote... that makes it all the more interesting.  Another question is why something like $d^3=0$ is not as interesting or practical.

Comment: There are certainly situations where one has $d^n=0$, and then a variant on homology (or several variants, depending on $i$) can be defined as $\textrm{ker} d^i/\textrm{im} d^{n-i}$.

Comment: @JohnPalmier Do you have any good examples of that on hand? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: @SantanaAfton: any graded module $M = \bigoplus M_i$ over the graded ring $k[x]/(x^n)$, with $x$ in degree $-1$, gives an example. Multiplication by the element $d$ gives a map $M_i \to M_{i-1}$ for each $i$.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I thought that might be the case :) And yet somehow the case with just $2$ is the workhorse.  Perhaps because it is the least complex thing that does what we want? Maybe there is an example for which at least $3$ is needed to do something that $2$ can't do... that would be a good addition for an interesting solution here.

Comment: Your instruction in the last paragraph to ignore homology is rather unfortunate. The motivations and intuitions behind the equation $d^2=0$ come from homology, and they are manifold (pun intended). Other usages of that equation are conceptually driven by mathematical efforts to widen the applicability of homological ideas, i.e. to addapt those ideas to broader and broader settings which stretch them beyond their manifold roots (pun intended once more!)

Comment: Thank you everyone for the responses. I worked through some standard facts (like the fact that we get an equivalence relation, nice behaviour under composition) about homotopic maps, homotopy equivalences, etc., and they all hold true without the condition that $d^2=0$. Can someone suggest where a commonly known fact about homoptic maps, homotopy equivalences might break if we leave out the condition that $d^2=0$?

Comment: A number of people have studied $N$-complexes (where $d^N=0$ in place of $d^2=0$), going back to Mayer in 1942. A fairly recent paper, with lots of references to previous work, is https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.6039

Comment: [Related mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/640/19965)

Answer (score 6):

The main motivation for wanting $d \circ d = 0$ is because it arises naturally in so many applications. As others have already said in comments, exact sequences are common and important, and you often get chain complexes by applying functors to exact sequences. At that point, homology measures how far the new sequence is from being exact: often a very interesting question.

More generally, people certainly study diagrams of the form
$$
X_1 \to X_2 \to X_3 \to \cdots
$$
with no condition on the maps, and then you can examine maps between such diagrams — the analog of chain maps. This happens all the time in algebra; for example, $X_i$ might be a submodule of $X_{i+1}$ for each $i$, giving a filtration of $\bigcup X_i$.

In the case when $d^2 \neq 0$, although I suppose the analog of "chain homotopy" could be defined, it is not clear what use it would be. What can you deduce if $f$ and $g$ are "chain homotopic" in this more general sense? What does it tell you in the case where each $X_i \to X_{i+1}$ is injective? Is surjective? When considering honest chain complexes, the definition of chain homotopy is motivated by the definition of homotopy in topology, and indeed, homotopic maps between topological spaces induce chain homotopic maps on their singular chain complexes: there is a mechanism for producing chain homotopies, at least in this one situation. Is there any mechanism that produces this analog of a chain homotopy? Without good motivating examples and/or interesting consequences, it doesn't seem worthwhile (to me, at least) to devote too much energy to it.

Comment: “It arises in so many applications”. Could you list two or three? The only place I’ve ever seen it in particular is with differential forms. Also, when you refer to some relationship with exact sequences, it is a complete mystery to me what the connection is, so I imagine it might be the case to others too. Could you explain that briefly in the solution?

Comment: @rschwieb: in algebraic topology, there are several ways to produce a chain complex from a suitable topological space: the singular, cellular, and simplicial chain complexes. Also in any exact sequence, you have $d^2=0$. Then if you apply a functor, say $- \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} G$ for your favorite abelian group $G$, you will get a sequence which may no longer be exact but has $d^2=0$. Read about homological algebra and group cohomology for two large areas which are replete with chain complexes and exact sequences.

Comment: @rschwieb: If you like more examples coming from analysis, take a look at [Cousin problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin_problems) which first appear as questions in complex analysis but they are best understood in terms of sheaf cohomology (which also provides some tools for solving the problems).

Comment: @JohnPalmieri That still flew far, far over my head, so I took a look at the wiki article. I was surprised to see that $d^2=0$ is apparently a shorthand for something I had not expected, namely pairwise relationships between the arrows in a sequence.  Is there some precise sense in which this is really an operator that squares to zero, or have I just been mislead by a convention?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Which parts flew over your head? Regarding $d^2 = 0$, can you clarify your question? It's in the title of the question here, and the setup should be a chain complex in which each map is called $d$, so the composite of two consecutive ones is $d \circ d := d^2$.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri The first sentence was over my head in the sense that I don't have any experience with those tools. The second sentence was an assertion that the very thing I'm asking about is true.  I understand the third sentence as an example of an application.  The last sentence suggests something I would like to do, but has a scope which I can't accommodate, now.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri In the meantime I've thought about $d$. My only picture for it right now is differential forms on $\mathbb R^n$, and that you can define it to take $k$ forms to $k+1$ forms, so really that should perhaps be $d_k$. I guess one could consider it a single map $d$ on the union of $k$ forms for positive integers $k$, but that union isn't a very sensible object, algebraically speaking.  I understand that might be one way to think of it though. Is that normally what is done? You think of all the connecting morphisms as "a single map"?

Comment: In the case of alternating $k$-forms, it looks like $d$ can be considered a function $\cup_{k\in\mathbb N} \Lambda ^k(V)\to \cup_{k\in\mathbb N} \Lambda ^k(V)$ which really does have square zero.  Not sure if that trick would work for general chain complexes, but that's OK.